# SocketIO emit won't fire inside express route

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

The following works fine, I can get the http response on my client app BUT the socketio emit doesn't seem to work. I have no idea why it is not firing.

Here's my code (some parts removed):

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var socketio = require('socket.io');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = socketio(server);

var beacons = require('./routes/beacons')(io);
app.use('/beacons', beacons);

server.listen(port, () => {
 console.log('Listening on port '+port);
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('beacon:show', function(data) {
    console.log('Show beacon: ' + data)
    socket.broadcast.emit('beacon:draw', data)
 })
});

module.exports = app;
```

**beacons.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(io) {
 router.get('/buy', function(req, res) {
    io.emit('beacon:show', {data: someData}) // Not Firing
    res.json({success: true})
 })

 return router
}
```

Comment: Do you have any error message ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your `io.emit()` inside an `io.on('connection', => {})`.

At the moment, you are sending in just the `io` variable, but *every single request and emission* needs to be wrapped inside a connection event. Otherwise how does socket.io know who it's sending it to, or if there's even anyone *to* send it to?

This can only really be done inside `beacons.js` and the `router.get('/buy')` section, because having it the other way around (a route wrapped inside a connection) won't work.